# How to update object in IndexedDB from service worker

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, service-worker

I'm trying to update an Object Store in IndexedDB from a Service Worker, this is my code right now:

```
function updateUrlLink(url_link) {
  var request = indexedDB.open('db', 1);
  var url_link_value = url_link;

  request.onsuccess = function (event) {  
    var store = request.result.transaction("url_link", "readwrite").objectStore("url_link");
    store.add(url_link_value, "url_link");
  };

  request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore('url_link');
  };

}
```

Is this the right way to update url_link or is there other way?